# generate refresh token after access token expires

Tags: node.js, amazon-cognito

I am currrently facing issue of generating refresh token after my access token is expired.I am using cognito-express in nodejs to validate my token and it works successfully.Major problem is of expiring accessToken after 1 hour i have also used javascript sdk amazon-cognito-identity-js but it also not working.So please help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: You should post the code that isn't working so we can help point out where the problems may be

Answer (score 0):

If you have a CognitoUser object created, you should be able to use the

```
CongitoUser.getSession((err, session) => { ... return session.getAccessToken().getJwtToken() }) method.
```

This automatically checks for the AccessToken expiration and refreshes it if the RefreshToken is still valid.